# Mutt - Missing emails

Tags: email, imap, mutt

I switched from Thunderbird to Mutt after a long time of googling on Mutt. I do not use anything like offlineimap or msmtp (should I?) etc, even though I would like to give it a try but I haven't figured out how to set them up yet (I haven't found a "proper" guide yet). Anyone has any tips on that, or generally on the most crucial parts of Mutt configuration?

My real problem though is this: I have configured Mutt for Gmail (IMAP) but there is a conversation that I am able to see in both the Gmail UI and Thunderbird, but NOT in Mutt. I cannot see why this is happening and I haven't found anything similar. Has anyone encountered the same problem? I do want to use Mutt but I want to be sure that every mail is fetched correctly. The messages I want to see are in the inbox of both Gmail UI and Thunderbird, so I don't think they are "lost" in trash or something. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Can you find those messages in `GMail/All Mail`?

There are only incomming messages in Inbox, Without your replies. I used to have the same issue with messages synced by offlineimap to local maildir. I just tried if it's the same with IMAP and it is. I'm afraid this is normal behaviour, since your sent mails are usually only in `Sent` and not in `Inbox`.

I switched to [gmailieer](https://github.com/gauteh/gmailieer) which use GMail API to get messages, [notmuch](https://notmuchmail.org/) for indexing them and virtual-mailboxes in neomutt. In mutt there's mutt-kz patch for this. Gmailieer keeps notmuch tags and gmail labels in sync. And solves also this issue since you can define mailbox to be composed whole of threads and not only messages.

e.g.:

```
virtual-mailboxes "INBOX"        "notmuch://?query=tag:inbox&type=threads"
```